# Scrollable MDL Content Tabs

Tags: html, css, tabs, material-design, angular-material

I understand in MDL that I can use the layout tab bar and create scrollable tabs, but is there a way to do this with the Content tabs? [Here](http://codepen.io/dustin486/full/WGLPvm/) is a codepen with the content tabs, but if you use too many of them they get jumbled together. I just prefer the look of content tabs over the layout tabs at the top nav bar.

```
<div class="mdl-tabs mdl-js-tabs mdl-js-ripple-effect">
    <div class="mdl-tabs__tab-bar">
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 4</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 5</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 6</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 7</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 8</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Tab 9</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 10</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 11</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 12</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 13</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 14</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 15</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 16</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 17</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 18</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 19</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab 20</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need so many of them, you probably shouldn't be using tab buttons in the first place. The preferred solution (accessibility and usability wise) is not to scroll them, but replace them with a drop-down list (vertically scrollable and searchable if necessary) containing all options.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu yeah I have considered using a drop down box, but I am really wanting to use the tabs. The amount of tabs isn't really a problem as they wouldn't all get used frequently. I am trying to get a look similar to how Google has theirs (search google for something like "mlb" and look how they show the schedules).

Comment: @dustin486 Did you ever find a solution to this? It is kind of annoying that the header tabs have a scrolling solution, but the team seem to have just forgotten about content tabs. I don’t really want to have to hack a solution. I would prefer to use the mdl solution.